# iPhone User Interface Guide - Editing top level data

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uitableview

I have a data-driven table view. The root view displays a list of entities (1) that when selected displays another list of entities (2).

If an entity in (1) has a series of properties that I'd like the user to have control over, what's the best UI approach to presenting them with a window for editing this data?

For example, if (1) was a list of Continents and (2) was a list of Countries, tapping a Continent will present a list of Countries and so on. If The user wanted to change a property of a Continent (example change "rateThisContinent") what does convention say he/she should tap?

I was originally thinking of a detail disclosure but that's not really in line with Apple's guidelines for what detail disclosure is.

An edit button might be the way to go, but then what would the table view display after the edit button has been pressed?

Thanks,

Glyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to answer my own question. I will create an intermediate 'detail view' after the (1) list that presents all the properties with a button to view the (2) list.

I'll then make the detail view editable.

Comment: Actually I see nothing wrong with using a detail disclosure button to reveal this detail view; you're editing details about a Continent, after all. Either way, it's your app :) Remember to accept your own answer if no others come along.